# Custom clipper not moving when I use Align

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart, user-experience

I am creating an UI which contains 5-6 polygons on the page. I inserted 2 of them. But when i try to move them using Align(), its not moving at all. Here is the code of mine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:online_schedule/bottomRightCorner.dart';
// import 'package:online_schedule/clipShadowPath.dart';

import 'bottomRightCorner.dart';
import 'middle.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(1, 1),
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: Middle(),
              child: Container(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-1, -1),
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: BottomRightCorner(),
              child: Container(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Forget about the co-ordinates that I mentioned, they are just for testing.
[what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbIqC.png)

The above image is the result of my code

But my goal is to get like this
[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Zet.jpg)

I have spent 3 days for this but still messed up. Help me guys

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in align

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:online_schedule/bottomRightCorner.dart';
// import 'package:online_schedule/clipShadowPath.dart';

import 'bottomRightCorner.dart';
import 'middle.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
           alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            //alignment: Alignment(1, 1),
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: Middle(),
              child: Container(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
           // alignment: Alignment(-1, -1),
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: BottomRightCorner(),
              child: Container(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not working even if I try this method